# How to add multiple cylinders to a surface in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, stl, surface

I am trying to add multiple cylinders to the surface in order to 3D print the model. I want to remove the points of the surface that fall within the cylinder.

The following is the code used to generate the surface

```
%% Generate Clebsch %%
CubeSize = 10;
Thickness = 0.1;
min = -CubeSize/2;
max = CubeSize/2;
v = linspace(min,max,200);
[x, y, z] = meshgrid(v);
a = sqrt(5);
c = sqrt(2);
figure(111)
clebsch_surface = 2*c*y.^3+2*x.^2.*z-8*y.^2.*z+3*c*y.*z.^2-z.^3-2*x.^2+8*y.^2-10*c*y.*z+3*z.^2+3*c*y-3*z+1;
fv = isosurface(x,y,z,clebsch_surface,0);
[f,v] = isosurface(x,y,z,clebsch_surface,0);
p = patch(fv);
isonormals(x,y,z,clebsch_surface,p);
p.FaceColor = 'red';
p.EdgeColor = 'none';
view([-65,20]);
camlight left;
lighting gouraud;
axis tight;
```

Then I need to find the lines that fall on the cylinders, so I have 27 formulas to determine these cylinders (I show two of the lines below) and then I want to determine a cylinder around each line and then remove the points within the cylinder of the surface and then convert the surface with the cylinders to a STL file

```
%% Generate the cylinders
for i=1:100
    a17(i,1) = 11/(a*c+4*c)*s(i)+3/(a*c+2*c);
    a17(i,2) = 5*s(i)/(a*c)-1/(a*c+2*c);
    a17(i,3) = s(i);
      a18(i,1) = (3/2*a*c+3*c)*s(i)-(a*c/2+2*c);
      a18(i,2) = -s(i)/(a*c-2*c)+a*c/2;
      a18(i,3) = s(i);   
  end 
R = 0.05;
N = 500;
[a17X,a17Y,a17Z]=cylinder2P(R,N,[a17(1,1) a17(1,2) a17(1,3)],[a17(100,1) a17(100,2) a17(100,3)]);
[a18X,a18Y,a18Z]=cylinder2P(R,N,[a18(1,1) a18(1,2) a18(1,3)],[a18(100,1) a18(100,2) a18(100,3)]);
```

Comment: I hope that old toolbox [geom3d](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24484-geom3d#functions_tab) can help you. It has functions for both shape construction and manipulation

Comment: If the main aim is to get the model and use of MATLAB is facultative, may be it is better to use some CAD with constraint-based parametric modeler like SolveSpace or OpenSCAD?